# Can anyone help me working with sencha touch in android?

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I would like to include sencha touch in my android project. Does anyone got any sample projects on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha is a company. They have several products. If you mean Sencha Touch, you can look on their [example page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/).

Comment: Thank you.. i wanted to use the sencha touch.